# Working example for the built-in SavitzkyGolayMatrix for doing polynominal smoothing

Tags: packages, filtering, signal-processing

Have been using various packages `SavitskyGolay.m` for Savitsky-Golay polynomial smoothing but just noticed the built-in matrix kernel. I am looking for an example for smoothing of uniformly sampled temporal data using the built-in kernel.

Take the following as a simple example

```
data = (Sin[#] + 0.3 RandomReal[]) & /@ Range[ 0, 2 π, .01];
data // ListPlot
```

Comment: For completeness: the [`SavitskyGolay.m`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/789/) package on the Wolfram Library Archive.

Comment: also see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160238/1259 for computing derivatives

Answer (score 12):

`SavitzkyGolayMatrix` produces a smoothing kernel that can be convolved with the data using `ListConvolve`.

Using your example and a kernel for a quadratic interpolation over the radius of 5:

```
data = (Sin[#] + 0.3 RandomReal[]) & /@ Range[0, 2 π, .01];

ListPlot@data
ListPlot@ListConvolve[SavitzkyGolayMatrix[{5}, 2], data]
```

[image: quadratically-smoothed data]

An example in 2D:

```
M = Table[Exp[-x^2 - y^2] + 
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1]], {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y, -2, 2, 0.1}];

ListContourPlot[M, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
ListContourPlot[ListConvolve[SavitzkyGolayMatrix[5, 2], M], InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image: quadratically-smoothed 2D data]

Please consider reading the detail section of `ListConvolve` for some common convolution settings.